# How to distribute points across the panel based on distance data?

Tags: c#, winforms, algorithm, traveling-salesman

So, I'm not sure how to properly explain this one, so if something is unclear ask in the comments, I'll try to use the exam question layout so you can easily spot restrictions.

Problem:

You're given an input of `Panel` (with fixed size), an array of `PointF[]` of fixed size `n`, and the distance data that contains distances between each pair of points in indexed arrays of size `n` which are accessed via `DistanceData` field in the following way:

`DistanceData[i].getDistances(k)` returns `int` which represents the distance between i-th and k-th point. As a corollary, the `DistanceData[k].getDistances(i)` returns the same value. If `i==k`, it returns `0`.

Your task is to update the `Panel` so that it honestly represents the `DistanceData` i.e. if `DistanceData[1].getDistances(3) < DistanceData[1].getDistances(4)` then the panel should display 1st and 3rd point closer than the 1st and 4th point etc.

Note: The distance data is inputted independently of the Points previously drawn on the Panel. Or rather, the Panel only contains the number of Points and you need to distribute them according to the values found in `DistanceData`.

Note#2: The tag "travelling-salesman" is there to remind you that all the points are dependent on each other i.e. all pairs have unique distance.

My take: The problem I'm facing is if I iteratively solve this - point by point, I find that I break the solution I did in the previous steps. To illustrate this: If I run a loop for 4 points and in the first iteration I draw the points based on the distances from the first point, the next step will almost certainly scrap that solution if it looks at the distances from the second point and so on...

Comment: Quite nice problem :-) One option is to look for some force-based-graph-layouting-algorithm. It should be much fun to implement it on your own!

Comment: imagine if you have 3 points (a triangle), then we may have many solutions of distribution, that means the multi-solutions are present. Your problem is not easy I think.

Answer (score 2):

If all you have is distance data, then there is more than one valid distribution of points.

You can translate your collection of points any distance in any direction, and the comparative distances will be the same. Therefore, we're free to choose whatever location we like to place the first point. Place point 1 at the origin, `(0, 0)`.

You can rotate your collection of points about any axis, and the comparative distances will be the same. Therefore, we're free to choose any location to place the second point, as long as it's the correct distance from the first point. Place point 2 at `(DistanceData[0].getDistances(1), 0)`.

There are two places where point 3 can go while still satisfying the distances with respect to points 1 and 2:

[image]

We can use the [Circle-Circle intersection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) formula to determine point 3's x coordinate.

```
d = distance between point 0 and point 1
R = distance between point 1 and point 3
r = distance between point 2 and point 3
x = (d^2 - r^2 + R^2)/(2*d)
```

There are two possible solution for point 3's y coordinate. You can find them by rearranging the terms in the Pythagorean formula.

```
y = sqrt(R^2 - x^2)
or
y = -sqrt(R^2 - x^2)
```

You can flip your collection of points over the x axis, and the comparative distances will be the same, so you can choose whichever of these y values you like. I prefer the positive one.

You now know the position of three points. You can then use [trilateration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration) to find the position of all other points.

Comment: But once again it doesn't solve the problem for all the distances. Say you use your method to find 6 points. So when you place 1st point at (0,0) and find the 2nd point based on the distances from that point to all the others. However, when doing that you consider all the points fixed, which isn't valid since you didn't find their position relative to their distance to other points...

Comment: _"So when you place 1st point at (0,0) and find the 2nd point based on the distances from that point to all the others."_ I'm finding the second point based only on the distance between the first and second points. The distances to all the other points aren't used at this stage.

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't work in this case, since all the points are mutually dependent, I need to take into calculations all the respective distances and represent all of them truthfully.

Comment: That's fine, all of the distances will be satisfied with this method. Unless no solution exists at all, of course. For instance, if A is 2 units away from B, and A is 3 units away from C, and B is 1000 units away from C.